# sub-interface/vlan not reachable

Tags: networking, network-bridge

I am not able to ping to sub-interface/vlan ip address that is configured in Ubuntu (14.04 or 16.04). Below is my configuration.

Can you please let me know if I am missing something. I googled and not able to find solution. My network configuration are good because, same vlan is working with CentOS.

**cat /etc/network/interface**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens160
Iface ens160 inet manual

auto ens160.20
iface ens160.20 inet static
address 172.18.135.23
gateway 172.18.135.254
netmask 255.255.252.0
vlan-raw-device ens160
```

**cat /etc/modules**

```
loop
lp
rtc
bonding
8021q
```

**dpkg -l | grep vlan**

```
ii  vlan                               1.9-3.2ubuntu1.16.04.1
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you checked if the interface actually comes up at boot? I'm experiencing a similar problem here where VLAN interfaces are not added to a bridge device at boot. While investigating the problem, I discovered that the VLAN interfaces simply don't come up at boot. What happens if you bring up `ens160.20` manually after the system has booted?